# Testing string for specific characters VB.NET

Tags: .net

I have a string that has FTP permissions - "LRSDCWAN" Is there a more efficiant way of checking the relevent CheckBox if the string contains the relevant character?

```
        If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("L") Then
            CBoxList.Checked = True
        End If
        If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("R") Then
            CBoxRead.Checked = True
        End If
        If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("S") Then
            CBoxSubDir.Checked = True
        End If
        If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("D") Then
            CBoxDelete.Checked = True
        End If
        If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("C") Then
            CBoxCreate.Checked = True
        End If
        If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("W") Then
            CBoxWrite.Checked = True
        End If
        If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("A") Then
            CBoxAppend.Checked = True
        End If
        If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("N") Then
            CBoxRename.Checked = True
        End If
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it doesn't get rid of your .Contains() problem, you can simplify the logic quite a bit.

If you notice, you are using:

```
If reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("L") Then
    CBoxList.Checked = True
End If
```

You can simplify this by just saying

```
CBoxList.Checked = reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("L")
```

You can do this for all of your checkboxes. It doesn't solve the needing to call contains, but it eliminates 2/3 of your lines of code.

Comment: Big maybe here ... if this is appropriate, this will also fix a bug that may exist with the OP's code, by unchecking items which aren't in the permission list. If though, OP is intentionally avoiding unchecking items, this will cause a bug.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT.. Doh, I missed the fact that it's a different checkbox for each character.

Okay, in that case I'd use a `Dictionary(Of Char, CheckBox)` for each character. Something like this - but in less broken VB :)

```
' Assumes VB10 collection initializers
Dim map As New Dictionary(Of Char, CheckBox) From {
    { "L", CBoxList },
    { "R", CBoxRead },
    { "S", CBoxSubDir },
    { "D", CBoxDelete },
    { "C", CBoxCreate }
}

For Each c As Char In reader.Item("home_perm")
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    If map.TryGetValue(c, cb) Then
        cb.Checked = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I think you overlooked that there is a separate checkbox for each value

Comment: Doh - didn't spot that. How annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(VS.71).aspx

OR

string.indexof method:

```
    Dim myString As String = "LRSDCW" 
    Dim myInteger As Integer 
    myInteger = myString.IndexOf("D") // myInteger = 4 
    myInteger = myString.IndexOf("N") // myInteger = -1
```

Use an Array for myInteger and check each member of the array for a value other than -1, if it is -1, don't check the box.

Comment: maybe not, its just my first thought for checking strings, alternatively, you can you the string.indexof method to get the position in the string of a letter, it will give -1 if it doesn't exits, its not elegant, but it will work

Comment: MaQleod: I don't think checking for containment of a single character is a problem here; Contains works fine. The problem is the repetition. I don't see how using regular expressions *or* IndexOf helps there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put all your comparision values in a generic list and walk the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
CBoxRename.Checked = (New Regex("[LRSDCWAN]").Match(reader.Item("home_perm")).Count > 0) ?
```

This is pretty inefficient - it's a brand new instance of a relatively intensive class every time, so you could cache one and reuse it if you wanted, but this way it fits neatly into one line.

Comment: Curses. Made the same mistake as the legendary Jon Skeet; so I don't feel too bad.

You can concatenate the same logic you've used in the form 
    Checkbox.Checked = reader.Item("home_perm").Contains("L")